# How to hide the browser interface while executing a php script?

Tags: c#, php, browser

I have a php script which i would need the following 3 web browsers to execute it respectively without revealing the respective browser interface to the user.

The 3 web browsers are,

Internet Explorer, Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox.

I found this C# code snippet but it is documented that it only works for Microsoft Products like Internet Explorer.

```
ProcessStartInfo PInfo;
Process Pro;
PInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
PInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
PInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Pro = Process.Start(Execute the Php script);
```

Can anyone advice me how can I hide the browser interface for the other (Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox) while executing the php script ? Please do give links or code snippets. (Preferably in C#).

Comment: php scripts are usually executed by web servers. web browsers are not capable of executing them, they merely display the results of execution returned by a webserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is server-side code.  A browser is client-side only.  This would be impossible without some intermediary code ran on the client's system. This would no doubt be classified as malware.

You can however, try to open up a popup and attempt to [hide that popup](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/threads/77051) --but this is unreliable since the client ultimately has the say on how their client behaves.  Most browsers already block popups blockers in place for this reason.

Another suggestion might be to be to simply insert an  within the webpage with style="visible: hidden" attribute set.  This will execute the PHP you seek without the direct knowledge of your client.  However, if your primary objective is to hide chrome/ff/ie, I don't think it can be done using white-hat methods.